# Java override issue (determine the parameter/return type in implementation class)

Tags: java

I really could not understand why this is not allowed in Java?!

An interface

```
package api;

public interface TreeNode {
    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root);
}
```

The implementation

```
package impl;

public class TreeNodeImpl implements api.TreeNode {
    @Override
    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNodeImpl root) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error doesn't make sense from my understanding:

[image]

Comment: Because the parameter is `TreeNodeImpl root` instead of `TreeNode root`. Is this a typographical error, or are you wondering why the parameter cannot be `TreeNodeImpl`?

Comment: The interface requires an implementation of a method that accepts _any TreeNode_. A method that accepts a specialisation of TreeNode would not suffice.

Comment: More or less the same reason `List<Cat>` isn't a subclass of `List<Animal>`.

Answer (score 0):

From your interface definition, each implementation of the interface `TreeNode` must have a method `isValidBST(...)` that takes a `TreeNode` as parameter. Your implementation `TreeNodeImpl`, on the other hand, only takes `TreeNodeImpl`s as parameter (a subset of all `TreeNode`s). For example, if there were some other `class OtherTreeNodeImpl implements TreeNode`, the calls

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNodeImpl();
node.isValidBST(new OtherTreeNodeImpl());
```

would lead to a compile time error, although they look perfectly fine when just looking at the interface. That is why the compiler claims (rightfully) that your method is not overriding the parent method.

---

You could use generics to solve your problem by specifying

```
public interface TreeNode<T extends TreeNode<T>> {
    public boolean isValidBST(T root);
}
```

and

```
public class TreeNodeImpl implements TreeNode<TreeNodeImpl> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNodeImpl root) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But for me, this seems like a dirty hack. Interfaces are supposed to reduce friction, but this interface introduces friction. Thus, you should design the interface `TreeNode` in such a way, that you only use methods defined in `TreeNode` within method `isValidBST(...)`. If designed correctly, you should be able to specify the implementation of `isValidBST(...)` as [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in `TreeNode`.